# Binding to an underlying ViewModel from an Adorner

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have created a slider control in an Adorner, named OpacityAdorner, intended on controlling the opacity of the control it belongs to. I have followed the Adorner example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part which uses xaml styles to help form the adorners, which possibly adds a little bit of complexity. 
At the moment, the only way I can find to hook the ValueChange of the slider, into the ViewModel, seems a little bit hacky, and I'd prefer to have a binding. I can't quite figure this out though:

```
protected override void OnInitialized( System.EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnInitialized( e );

        if( m_chrome != null && m_chrome.Template != null && m_slider == null )
        {
            m_chrome.ApplyTemplate();
            m_slider = m_chrome.Template.FindName( "OpacitySlider", m_chrome ) as Slider;
            if( m_slider != null )
            {
                m_slider.ValueChanged += opacity_value_changed;
                //Binding opacityBinding = new Binding( "OpacityValue" );
                //Control ctrl = (Control)m_chrome.DataContext;
                //SettingsViewModel settingsVM = ctrl.DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
                //opacityBinding.Source = settingsVM;
                //////opacityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath( "OpacitySlider" );
                //m_slider.SetBinding( SettingsViewModel.OpacticyProperty, opacityBinding );
            }
            m_opacity_button = m_chrome.Template.FindName( "OpacitySliderEnable", m_chrome ) as Ellipse;
            if( m_opacity_button != null )
            {
                m_opacity_button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += m_opacity_button_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            }
        }           
    }
```

and

```
void opacity_value_changed( object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e )
    {
        Control ctrl = (Control)m_chrome.DataContext;
        SettingsViewModel settingsVM = ctrl.DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
        settingsVM.OpacityValue = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Ideally I'd just like to get the binding working in the part commented out, remove the opacity_value_changed event. I'd also like to know if there's a neater way to retrieve the SettingsViewModel, without first getting the container chrome control, then getting the view model from it's DataContext?

Comment: According to MVVM, your view must not be aware of what type the viewmodel is of. So, you shouldn't write something like `DataContext as ViewModel`. Consider inspecting your bindings. And, post your XAML markup.

Comment: @dymanoid I disagree. The view is automatically  aware of the ViewModel from the moment you do `{Binding SomeProperty}`. Also, your statement implies that one should use complicated, overengineered, often completely unneeded stuff such as creating an interface for the viewmodel and use DI to inject an instance into the view, which is total nonsense for simple scenarios. I totally disagree with your statement.

Comment: @HighCore, well, data binding is exactly the thing that allows the view to ignore the concrete viewmodel type (implementation). The only thing you tell writing `{Binding SomeProperty}` is that the `DataContext` object could have a property with this name. It's even not necessary, by the way. Using strong types in the view ties it to one exact viewmodel implementation, which isn't actually the MVVM idea: separate the data and the view.

Comment: @dymanoid whatever, keep doing your senseless unnecessary abstractions, I'll keep being pragmatic (as opposed to dogmatic) and use the best tool for the job every time. It's precisely because of people like you that MVVM is so frowned upon.

Comment: As I say, I'd rather not cast any DataContext, or do the code I have done. It is a bit horrible. But it works and it's the only way I can seem to get it to work. I could post a lot of xaml, but not sure it will help. I am basically taking the example in the link I posted, and directly adapting it for a few of my uses. Hence the need to get the control from the chrome datacontext, then get the view model from the control datacontext! Ugly!